# I always hear my in-line mic, even if the mic is disabled

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, microphone

I own a laptop with a headphone/mic combo jack. When I plug the headphones with in-line mic in, I will always hear the input from the mic, regardless of whether or not the `Listen to this device` button is checked in Windows audio settings

I disabled and muted all of the microphones using the Windows audio control panel, but I still hear the feedback. **How do I turn it off?**

**TL;DR**: OP has a headset with in line mic, and an audio combo port, but whenever he plugs the headset in, he **always** hears it through the headset.

```
System info:
    Koss PortaPro KTC
    Lenovo Y-50 Touch
```

Comment: Try a different headset with mic, if the problem goes away then it's the way the headset is wired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use Realtek's HD Audio manager, and disable listening to the microphone there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows 11 do the following:

SETTINGS > Home >Sound > More sound settings > Playback > Click on properties for your inline speakers > Levels > Now either mute or turn down the microphone.

Still allows you to play external microphones through like if you have a voice changer

My issue was I could hear myself and the voice changer through my speakers and doing this allowed me to stop hearing myself and only the voice changer.

If your looking to do this and you don't want to hear the voice changer through your speakers either, then the voice changer you're using should have a built-in feature. If not then you have to go into the microphone properties setting for the name of your voice changer and do the same thing you did for your speakers.